# Hopefully you can make the connection

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

**These are connected somehow, hopefully you can see how. The answer I'm looking for is 17 letters long.**

---

```
            CONNECT
```

*All...are evenly spaced with..at the bottom* **(4)**

*All...are evenly spaced with..at the bottom
 and a-line just below the top.* **(3)**

*All...are evenly spaced with..at the top* **(5)**

*All...are evenly spaced with..at the top
 and a-line just above the bottom.* **(5)**

---

**Edit:** I made some changes. I wasn't completely satisfied with how it was presented so here's the new version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took this rather literally.

All...are evenly spaced with..at the bottom (4).

> All 3 dots are evenly spaced with 2 dots at the bottom. If you connect those 3 dots, you get an equilateral triangle.

All...are evenly spaced with..at the bottom
and a-line just below the top. (3).

> Same, but now there is a (horizontal or dashed) line just below the top.

All...are evenly spaced with..at the top (5).

> This is then an upsidedown equilateral triangle.

All...are evenly spaced with..at the top and a-line just above the bottom. (5).

> Same, but with a line through it as before.

> The original question mentioned "we" so we are looking for a collection of four items matching these shapes. I was stuck at this point for a day or two, but when the enumerations were added I was thinking of sets of four and noticed that these enumerations match the classical [elements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element). And I looked it up, and it turns out those elements have official symbols:
>  [image: elements]
>  What do you know.... The puzzle is solved!

You are the:

> CLASSICAL ELEMENTS (17).

Comment: Indeed it is. Great job!

Comment: Well done! I was looking in entirely the wrong direction: at the distribution of letters, vowels, consonants, ascenders, descenders etc in 17-letter words. I stopped when I realised there could be two or more words. I had been egged on by finding that there are a number of words with alternating consonants and vowels, or with a vowel every 3rd place, etc.